# Using PHP MVC with OOP correctly

Tags: php, correctness

I've been reading and learning about OOP and MVC for the last week or so I would like to know if I'm on the right track.

Here is an example of what I currently have:

index.php
Parses the URL that is passed in from Apache mod_rewrite (.htaccess). In this file I also first include my site specific settings and defined variables, then I include the related controller file and then the view.

```
<?php
// Include the site specific settings
require 'includes/settings.php';

// Include the HTML page header
require LIBPATH . 'views/page_header.php';

//Code to parse the url passed in from mod_rewrite
require LIBPATH . 'controllers/' . $require_url . '.inc.php';
require LIBPATH . 'views/' . $require_url . '.php';

// Include the HTML page footer
require PUBLICPATH . 'includes/page_footer.php'; 
?>
```

Moving on to the controller:
In this file I make sure that the form $_POST is set and then invoke the model (class).

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
  $loginUser = new User();
  $loginUser->email = $_POST['email'];
  $loginUser->password = $_POST['password'];
  $returnArray = (json_decode($loginUser->select(), true));
  $_SESSION['userID'] = $loginUser->userID;
  $_SESSION['firstName'] = $loginUser->firstName;
  $_SESSION['lastName'] = $loginUser->lastName;
  $_SESSION['email'] = $loginUser->email;
  // Redirect code to admin area of the site
}
?>
```

Now the model (class) code:

```
<?php
// Basically I'm interacting with the database and returning the data in a JSON encoded array. This is always where I check to make sure that values are set and correct before doing the database queries.
?>
```

Is this a correct way of using MVC and PHP OOP?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Look through these answers http://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/teresko?tab=answers&sort=votes

Comment: Sorry but this is not MVC nor OOP. [A simple MVC concept Tut](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I agree with MVC but why its not OOP ? Not even a bit ?

Comment: Thank you for the links @Esailija. I just finished reading through all of them and they were very helpful.

Comment: @YousufMemon , because the code used here is [non-structured programming paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-structured_programming), the `User` instance seems without any encapsulation, violates SRP .. etc. Basically, it's bad. The author should start by picking up [PHP Object-Oriented Solutions](http://www.amazon.com/PHP-Object-Oriented-Solutions-David-Powers/dp/1430210117) and read all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a framework.  Take a look at [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/).  Its not the best MVC framework, but it's the only one I've used for php.

Comment: +1 I've used several frameworks and for me CI is the best, might try symphony 2 soon

Comment: Thank you for the framework suggestion but I'm really to learn the concepts of MVC and OOP and don't want to use a framework at this time.

Comment: codeigniter is a MVC framework.  For MVC it will provide you with file structure and a way for your models, controllers and views to interact with each other.  Its models and views are both implemented via classes.  It is literally everything you want.  If build some applications in Code Igniter, by the end you should understand OOP and MVC to some degree.

Comment: If you use CodeIgniter to learn about OOP and MVC, then you are doing it wrong. It is a horrible piece of code, filled with global state, php4 artifacts and violation of OOP principles, concepts and laws. And it's interpretation of MVC pattern is bad even by PHP standards.